# AJUDA COM A CRIAÇÃO DE UM SISTEMA DE AUTOMATIZAÇÃO

Tags: automatização

Fechada. Essa pergunta é fora de escopo e não está atualmente aceitando respostas.
Apesar de ser sobre programação, esta pergunta não parece atender os critérios mínimos de qualidade e detalhamento para um site de perguntas e respostas. As perguntas aqui precisam ser para problemas específicos, práticos ou conceituais sobre algoritmos, ferramentas e técnicas de programação e desenvolvimento de software. Melhore a pergunta.

Fechada 4 horas atrás.

Preciso de dicas e sugestões para poder desenvolver uma aplicação que vai ficar dentro de um serviço escutando um calendário carregado direto de um banco de dados MYSQL.

Ao bater a data e hora do registro com a atual ele roda uma atualização dos dados de um banco de dados MYSQL podendo atualizar ou criar novos itens vindos de uma API REST.

ISSO PRECISA RODAR AUTOMATICAMENTE 1X POR DIA E SE DER ERRO TEM QUE ENVIAR UM LOG DE ERRO POR E-MAIL.

ALGUEM TERIA UMA DICA OU SUGESTÃO DE LINGUAGEM OU TECNOLOGIAS POSSO UTILIZAR ?

Comment: Queira editar sua [postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/561405/) conforme links do quadro de fechamento de lá. Para evitar informaçoes em duas postagens, o campo de comentários desta aqui está desativado, mas na postagem original pode ser usado.